# Resize images for object detection

Tags: object-detection, resize-image

I want to train images with mask RCNN and my understanding is that all the images need to be the same size. I also read that you can add "padding" to images so that you can retain the right aspect ration.

Does anyone know how to add padding to the images and resize?Does anyone have a code for that or an online tool which can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In opencv library, there are padding function that can add borders to your images.

also, resize function too.

refer to [this webpage.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html)

[image]